# How to assign new `styler` object to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Why can't I assign a new style to pandas dataframe? The following assignment (*last line*) doesn't work but I would like to change a style of a given dataframe in some functions and such a functionality would be great:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def color_negative(v, color):
    return f"color: {color};" if v < 0 else None
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=["A", "B"])
s = df.style
s = s.applymap(color_negative, color='green', subset=["B"])
s = s.applymap(color_negative, color='red', subset=["A"])
 
df.style = s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to emulate the `styler.use` and `.export` methods.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def color_negative(v, color):
    return f"color: {color};" if v < 0 else None
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=["A", "B"])
s = df.style
s = s.applymap(color_negative, color='green', subset=["B"])
s = s.applymap(color_negative, color='red', subset=["A"])
s = s.export()

df.style.use(s)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt solve my problem. When I call df.style after all your code then the cells are not coloured so it doesnt assign `s` to `df.style`

Comment: when you call `df.style` it **always** creates a new, completely unstyled `Styler` object. That is the point of then adding the `.use(s)`, so that the styles that have previously been applied to the styler object `s`, and exported, are imported and used on the new object you create. See my image.

Comment: `df.style = s` (from your question) is not a valid line of code, and should not be used.

Comment: ok but let's say that I have two functions: `f1` and `f2`. I want pass `DataFrame`  `df`as an argument to `f1` and highlight some values. This function should return `df` with edited style and then I would like to use this `df` in the `f2` to do some other formatting. In your solution I have to pass both `df` and `s` as an argment to `f2`.